# Jackson Serialization of XML with multiple attributes

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, fasterxml

Trying to figure out how to serialize an xml payload with jackson that has multiple attributes(?) as well as namespaces or locals.

I need the payload to look like this:

```
<wfs:GetFeature xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:fade="http://www.bit-sys.com/fade" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" resultType="results" maxFeatures="150001" outputFormat="application/json">
        <wfs:Query srsName="EPSG:4326" typeName="ExampleTypeName">
            <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
                ...
```

And I am working on creating a pojo to use to map the data necessary for this payload to the correct location, but just having trouble differentiating the `namespace` vs `localName` parts. The pojo I have so far isn't really producing the desired result (even for the first `<GetFeature />` part.

```
public class MyXmlObject {

  @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "wfs", namespace = "wfs")
  class GetFeature {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String wfs = "http://www.opengis.net/wfs";

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String ocg = "http://www.opengis.net/ogc";

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String fade = "http://www.bit-sys.com/fade";

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String service;

    @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "wfs")
    public class Query {

      @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
      private String srsName = "exampleSrsName";

      @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
      private String typeName = "exampleTypeName";

    }

  }

}
```

Right now only running a simple test to see how my xml payload looks as I work on it produces `<MyXmlObject />` with nothing else in it, not too sure what I am doing wrong.

```
@Test
public void whenJavaSerializedToXmlStr_thenCorrect()
    throws JsonProcessingException {
  XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
  xmlMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
  String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(new MistXmlObject());
  System.out.print(xml);
}
```